# Create a 10x10 matrix filled with random integers from 1 - 99 using functions (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, matrix

I am writing some code that has 2 functions. The first function I believe has no problems. The first one is to create the 10x10 matrix filled with random numbers, the second function is to print the matrix. The problem that I am having is that even with the declaration of the row and column sizes, the matrix prints out in one line and not in a grid-like shape. I have tried to use the setw to end the line when the limit reaches 10. I am new to programming so I am not sure why the array is not printing the way it should.

This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int ROW_SIZE = 10;
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 10;

void initialize(int [][10], int, int);
void display(int matrix[][10], int, int);

int main() {

    int matrix [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];

    initialize(matrix, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE);

    display(matrix, ROW_SIZE,COLUMN_SIZE);


    return 0;
}


//question 1
void initialize(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            matrix[i][j] =  1 + rand() % 99;
        }
    }
}

//question 2
void display(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            cout<< setw(4)<<matrix[i][j]<< " ";
        }
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Since this is C++, why not make a matrix class?

Comment: Hint: After each row is printed, `std::cout << std::endl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not ever printing an end of line character. Setw(n) will tell cout that every chunk of text that you write has to be printed using exactly n characters, but it doesn't say that that chunk of text has to end in a newline.

To make sure that there's a new line after every row of your matrix, you could write cout << endl, or cout << '\n' (a fancy character meaning "start a new line") after printing each row. Both of which explicitly tell the computer to add a new line.